# Why is atoi returning random numbers?

Tags: c, integer, atoi

I am trying to read in data from a text file (the time). and convert that into something that can be DiffTime'ed to the current system time.

I am now so close to getting this working correctly, I can taste it but I am stuck with an issue I cannot work out. (I have a very basic grasp of the C language).

this program reads in the data from the text file, splits it into two char arrays, and then  tries to use [`atoi`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/atoi.html) to convert this into an integer. However, I am getting problems with the second `atoi` call.

From the bottom two [`printf`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/printf.html) statements, I should be getting:

```
12  
34
```

but for some reason i am getting something along these lines.

```
12  
3412
```

I presume that `atoi` is overunning the boundries of one of the char arrays or my char arrays are too long or too short. Either way, I cannot fathom what is going on.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define COPYMODE 0644

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    int  i, nRead, fd;

    int  source;
    int  ihour;
    int  imin;

    int  STATE_OK = 0;
    int  STATE_WARNING  = 1;
    int  STATE_CRITICAL = 2;
    int  STATE_UNKNOWN  = 3;
    /* indicates if system is paused 1 = System is paused, 0 = System running */
    int  system_paused  = 0; 

    char filebuf[5]; 
    char hourbuf[2];
    char minbufer[2];

    if((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1)
    {
        printf("failed open : %s", argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        nRead = read(fd, filebuf, 5);
    }
    close(source);

    printf("filebuffer %s\n", filebuf);

    hourbuf[0] = filebuf[0];
    hourbuf[1] = filebuf[1];

    printf("Hour Buffer %c%c\n", hourbuf[0],hourbuf[1]);

    minbufer[0] = filebuf[2];
    minbufer[1] = filebuf[3];

    printf("Min Buffer %c%c\n", minbufer[0],minbufer[1]);

    imin = atoi(minbufer);
    ihour = atoi(hourbuf);


    printf("hour as int %d\n", ihour);
    printf("min as int %d\n", imin);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to terminate your `char` buffers with zero.

```
char hourbuf[2];
char minbufer[2];
```

Should be

```
char hourbuf[3];
char minbufer[3];

hourbuf[2] = '\0';
minbufer[2] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to null terminate the strings.  Make hourbuf and minbufer 1 longer and put a 0 at the end before calling atoi.  The two buffers are adjacent on the stack, so reading minbufer scans into hourbuf as well.

Comment: +1, because you also gave a good explanation for the strange '3412' output.

Comment: my brain was telling me this, but i could not work out how to stop it doing it, which was driving me nuts. i came from a programming background where there was no "null termination" so i keep forgetting it.... :)

thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` assumes its argument is a C-style string, which means it must contain a trailing nul character.

Your handcrafted pseudostrings don't ensure this.

A solution would be to enlarge them and set the last element to `'\0`:

```
char hourbuf[3];
int hour;
...
hourbuf[0] = filebuf[0];
hourbuf[1] = filebuf[1];
hourbuf[2] = '\0';
hour = atoi(hourbuf);
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to null terminate:

```
minbufer[2] = '\0'
```

Comment: Your idea is right, so I'm not downvoting.  However, I suspect you got a downvote because you didn't point out that minbufer needs to have 3 chars ..

Comment: I considered it, but I decided that the coder REALLY should be able to work that out hisself.

Comment: your correct as well Alex :) i would have worked that one out, proberbly not as quickly as you guys but it would have hit me. this language is a real learning curve for me :)

cheers for the reply.